# Rust の Enigo で使用するキーコードがわからない

Tags: rust, key-mapping, key-binding

Rustにて、キーボードの入力をエミュレートするためにEnigoを使用しています。
https://docs.rs/enigo/latest/enigo/

### やりたいこと

文字を入力できる`enigo.key_click(Key)`に渡すKeyの値として、aなど単純な文字のキーなら`enigo::Key::Layout(char)`という形で出せます。しかし最終的に**英数キーやかなキーもエミュレートしたい**と考えており、`enigo::Key::Raw(u16)`の方を使ってキーを指定していこうとしています。

### 問題

`enigo::Key::Raw(u16)`は[ドキュメント](https://docs.rs/enigo/latest/enigo/enum.Key.html)にて

> raw keycode eg 0x38

と書かれており、u16にはキーコードを渡せばよいということになります。しかし、どうもここの数値と入力される文字との対応関係が、例えば、"65(0x41)"なら"a"が入力されるような**一般的なキーコードのそれと一致しない**ようなのです。
（「一般的な」とは、『質問者が記憶している』および『「キーコード」で検索するとおおかた出てくる』の意味です）

### 試したこと1

まず、`enigo::Key::Raw(u16)`に一般的なキーコードでの「かな」「英数」に相当する値を渡して実行してみました。

```rust
use enigo::{Enigo, Key, KeyboardControllable};

fn main() {
    let mut enigo = Enigo::new();

    enigo.key_click(Key::Raw(240));//英数
    //enigo.key_click(Key::Raw(242));//かな
}
```

どちらの場合も入力ソースの変化はなく、何も起こりませんでした。

### 試したこと2

"65"を指定しました。一般的なキーコードだと"a"が入力されるはずです。

```rust
use enigo::{Enigo, Key, KeyboardControllable};

fn main() {
    let mut enigo = Enigo::new();

    enigo.key_click(Key::Raw(65));
}
```

実行後、コンソールに入力されたのは以下でした。

```
.
```

### 試したこと3

```rust
use enigo::{Enigo, Key, KeyboardControllable};

fn main() {
    let mut enigo = Enigo::new();

    enigo.key_click(Key::Raw(0));
    enigo.key_click(Key::Raw(1));
    enigo.key_click(Key::Raw(2));
    enigo.key_click(Key::Raw(3));
    enigo.key_click(Key::Raw(4));
    enigo.key_click(Key::Raw(5));
    enigo.key_click(Key::Raw(6));
    enigo.key_click(Key::Raw(7));
    enigo.key_click(Key::Raw(8));
}
```

ひとまず手あたり次第に0~8番の文字を入力するコードを書きました。
これを実行して、コンソールに入力された文字は以下の通りです。

```
asdfhgzxc
```

つまり、対応関係としては以下のようになります。

- 0: a
- 1: s
- 2: d
- 3: f
- 4: h
- 5: g
- 6: z
- 7: x
- 8: c
  ...
- 65: .

**このような対応関係の「キーコード」をご存知の方はいらっしゃるでしょうか？** あるいは、それが見られるサイトなどはありますでしょうか。
少なくとも自分には「なんとなくキーボードの配列が関係している」以上の関係は見出せません。キー番号を一通りループさせたとしても、かな・英数がどのキーかは判別できないでしょう。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

質問の実行環境はmac OSのようですね。詳しくないですが、この場合はCocoaの情報を調べるのがよいと思います。
参考: [Where are all the Cocoa keycodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36900825/where-are-all-the-cocoa-keycodes)

なお、Enigo というライブラリのソースを見ると、これは環境毎のAPIやライブラリの薄いラッパーのようですので、WindowsやLinuxではまた違ったコードになるでしょう。(Linux環境用の `Key::Raw` は未実装のようです)

Comment: Cocoaのキーコードについて調べたところ、見事に一致しました。また、これを踏まえ、前から参考プロジェクトにリストアップしていた英かな（https://github.com/iMasanari/cmd-eikana）を詳しく掘ったところ、ソースコードに全キーコードが書いてあり、かな・英数の動作も実現できました。ありがとうございました！